# Bounce picturebox up and down

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Made progress on my game and now I need to make the second boss bounce up and down. I figured out how to make the boss go down, but once it touches the lower wall, it stops and won't bounce (move up).

```
    void BossMove()
    {
        if((BOSS.Top + 10) <(this.Height - BOSS.Height))
        {
            BOSS.Top += 10;
        }
        if((BOSS.Height) > 0)
        {
            BOSS.Top -= 10;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume you are on `WinForms` ? please specify in your tags whether it is `WinForms` or `WPF`

Comment: What second `if` is doing? I would expect you to have `increment` variable (used like this `Boss.Top += increment`), which sign you change to opposite after edge hit test.

Comment: I am using winforms

Comment: Sinatr Can you explain that a little more? I tried what you suggested and it still doesn't bounce back up after touching the wall.

Comment: `if((BOSS.Height) > 0)`  Does the HEIGHT of the boss change (probably not)?  This will most likely always be true so you'll always be moving down?

Comment: Is Boss in the code your picturebox? I am not full understand how your picturebox moved. Can you describe it in more detail? Also, it will better for you to show the related picture about your game.

Comment: Yes BOSS is the picturebox in the game. I tried what everyone said and I just can't figure it out. I tried... if(BOSS.Top <= 450){BOSS,Top -= 10;} amongst other ideas and nothing is working. Can someone please help me I really am trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example using a state variable to represent the direction:

```
private Boolean goingUp = true;

void BossMove()
{
    if (goingUp)
    {
        if ((BOSS.Top + 10) < (this.Height - BOSS.Height))
        {
            BOSS.Top += 10;
        }
        else
        {           
            // possibly force it to snap to specific position
            // before going back down?
            goingUp = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (BOSS.Top > 450)
        {
            BOSS.Top -= 10;
        }
        else
        {
            // possibly force it to snap to specific position
            // before going back up?
            goingUp = true;
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: I wish I could vote your answer up. Thank you so much. I also figured it out over the weekend more or less how to make it work, although its not as clean as your code. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad you figured something out.  Out of curiosity, why can't you vote an answer up?

Comment: It says I need a reputation of 15 to vote. It took my vote but it won't display it. I will definitely follow you on stack over flow.